# Components do not re-render after calling store.writeQuery()

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

So I am following the graphql + apollo tutorial at https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/6-more-mutations-and-updating-the-store/ and I have a bunch of "Link" components that when upvoted should show the new number of votes. So far it does not re-render when upvoted and I have to refresh the page.

I try to do this by calling store.writeQuery() with the updated data. I checked and the data object I passed in is indeed different from the old:

Here's my initial set-up:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory"
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import App from './components/App';
import {AUTH_TOKEN} from "./constants.js";

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => 
{
    const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
    return {
        headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: (token ? "Bearer " + token : ""),
    }
  }
});

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000"
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Here's the mutation component:

```
<Mutation 
            mutation={VOTE_MUTATION}
            variables={{id: this.props.link.id}}
            update={(store, { data: { upVote } }) =>
            {
              const data = store.readQuery({ query: FEED_QUERY });

              const votedLink = data.feed.links.find(link => link.id === this.props.link.id);
              votedLink.votes = upVote.link.votes;
              console.log(data);
              store.writeQuery({ 
                query: FEED_QUERY, 
                data,
              });
            } }
            >
            {
            mutationCallback =>
              (<div className="ml1 gray f11" style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={mutationCallback}>
                ▲
              </div>)
            }
              </Mutation>
```

Here's the query that fetches all the links:

```
const FEED_QUERY = gql`
{
    feed
    {
        links
        {
            id url description createdAt 
            createdBy{
                name email
            } 
            votes{
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
`;
```

And I call store.readQuery() and store.writeQuery() with the expectation that the upvoted link will rerender to show the new number of votes. I also log the passed in data object to ensure it has been updated, and it has. But no rerendering. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to the apolloClient dataIdFromObject for more info here the: [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates/)

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    dataIdFromObject: o => o.id 
})
```